# How to verify and change a JWT Alg

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, aspnet-contrib

I'm using the ASP.Net OpenID Connect Server project (ASOS) to create and consume JWTs for my WebAPI.

I'm now trying to perform various validations on the token.

I'd like to know how to check the "alg" type.
I'm aware of an issue where "none" can be passed in, which means that someone can forge the tokens (I'm not sure if it's just specific libraries that have the issue, or if it's just generally good practice to check, but I'd feel safer if I was performing that check).

Also, how can I verify the integrity of the JWT?

Currently my token issuer and WebAPI are in the same project so I'm guessing that it's checked for me automatically? Or is it not checked at all?

My understanding is that some kind of signing credential is added for you on disk if you don't specify any (Not sure where I read that).

Would providing some kind of signing credential automatically update the "alg" property?

What if my token issuer is on 1 server and my WebAPI was somewhere completely different.  How would I go about validating that the token came from my token issuer and hadn't been interfered with.

Presumably I'd have to add a certificate manually, then share the public key somehow?
If that's the case, could someone point me to where I should add the public key to check the JWT integrity?
Presumably this part is more about asp.net Core than OpenIDConnect Server (ASOS)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know how to check the "alg" type.

You can use a tool like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to read the header of a JWT, which contains the `alg` value you're looking for.

> I'm aware of an issue where "none" can be passed in, which means that someone can forge the tokens (I'm not sure if it's just specific libraries that have the issue, or if it's just generally good practice to check, but I'd feel safer if I was performing that check).

ASOS relies on IdentityModel - a framework developed by Microsoft - to generate the JWT tokens (you can take a look at [this other answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38542062/542757)). AFAIK, it was not impacted by the security bug you're mentioning.

To try it yourself, you can use jwt.io to alter the `alg` header value and send the resulting encoded JWT to your API.

> Also, how can I verify the integrity of the JWT?
>
> Currently my token issuer and WebAPI are in the same project so I'm guessing that it's checked for me automatically? Or is it not checked at all?
>
> What if my token issuer is on 1 server and my WebAPI was somewhere completely different. How would I go about validating that the token came from my token issuer and hadn't been interfered with.
>
> Presumably I'd have to add a certificate manually, then share the public key somehow? If that's the case, could someone point me to where I should add the public key to check the JWT integrity? Presumably this part is more about asp.net Core than OpenIDConnect Server (ASOS)?

If you use the JWT bearer middleware, then it's automatically done for you. For that, it directly downloads the public signing keys exposed by [ASOS' JWK set endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-5) (by default, at `/.well-known/jwks`).

Here's an example:

[image: JWK Set]

> My understanding is that some kind of signing credential is added for you on disk if you don't specify any (Not sure where I read that).

This is true with the latest official version (beta6) but this feature will be removed in the next version. You'll be encouraged to register a X.509 certificate or use an ephemeral signing key (during development). An exception will be thrown if you don't.

> Would providing some kind of signing credential automatically update the "alg" property?

Yes. ASOS natively supports both symmetric keys and RSA keys. For instance, if you use a `SymmetricSecurityKey` when calling `options.SigningCredentials.AddKey(...)`, `HS256` (HMAC-SHA256) will be returned instead of `RS256` (RSA-SHA256). You can provide additional algorithms using the `Add` overload accepting a `SigningCredentials` instance.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Can you please clarify the following points:
-When I said that I wanted to check the "alg" type, I meant programmatically, how can I do that?
-I just tried the well known endpoint you mentioned and it shows content similar to your screenshot.
--How does the jwtBearer middleware know where to look though?  If the WebAPI is on a different webserver, how do I point it to the right location?

Comment: As mentioned in the last section, the `alg` value directly depends on the `SigningCredentials` you register. You can control the value there. The JWT bearer middleware knows how to contact the authorization server because you set the issuer address when assigning `Authority` in the JWT options.

Comment: Sorry, regarding the "alg" I don't think I'm being specific enough.

What I mean to say is that I want to examine the "alg" for an in-coming  token, not how to set it at the point of creation (For this particular question I have).

Thank you for clarifying the JWT bearer middleware Authority, that makes perfect sense.