# ASP.NET Core OpenIdConnectServer data protection keys location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

Hello,

In my ASP.NET Core application I'm using an OpenIdConnectServer for Api authentication. Everything works fine.

But there is one thing I cannot resolve - how to set custom folder for persisting token signing keys?

In service configuration I have:

```cs
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"keys/"));
```

After first run, an application key is created there.
But the OpenIdServer manages the keys somehow by itself.

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options => {
    ...
    options.DataProtectionProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetDataProtectionProvider();
    ...
});
```

Despite that, the credentials signing key is created in default location:

```cs
 A new RSA key ... persisted on the disk: /home/.../.aspnet/aspnet-contrib/oidc-server/<some guid>.key.
```

Is that bug or a feature? How can I force the server to store the keys also in the `keys/` folder?

---

*Abstract - why I'm doing this*:

My idea is to build an API from *n* docker images of this, hide it behind an load ballancer and run somewhere in the cloud. The problem is - when every instance in docker creates it's own application&signing key, the encrypted   auth token will not work for any other instance except the one, that has created and signed the token with it's key.
Therefore, I'm trying to distribute the same keys to every docker image running. To an pre-defined application folder, if possible.

Or is there any better approach or best practice?

---

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: FYI, the OIDC server middleware doesn't change the way DataProtection keys are managed, but it's not the only keys it uses as there are actually 2 separate serialization mechanisms, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541772/authorize-via-jwt-token/38542062. The debug message you're seeing is logged by the internal RSA key generation feature, that creates asymmetric keys for id_token signing. Note that this feature was mainly for development purposes and will be removed in the next beta (beta7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

First, we have to generate a x509 certificate (with private key) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480846/x-509-private-public-key)

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key private.key -out publickey.cer -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey private.key -in publickey.cer
```

Copy it to the folder you like, `key/certificate.pfx` in this case.

Then, gently insert your new certificate to OpenIdConnectServer:

*appsettings.json*

```
"Keys": {
    "CertificatePath": "keys/certificate.pfx",
    "CertificatePassword": "<password you provider>"
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
private X509Certificate2 CreateOauthCertificate(){
        var path = Configuration["Keys:CertificatePath"];
        var password = Configuration["Keys:CertificatePassword"];
        return new X509Certificate2(path, password);
    }
```

*Starup.cs - Configure*

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(
    ...
    options.SigningCredentials.AddCertificate(CreateOauthCertificate());
    ...
});
```

Now I'm curious if there is a better way or not.

But this works.

Regards

Comment: I have wondered a point. If you store `CertificatePath` and `CertificatePassword` into environment variables(or store with using secret manager tool) instead of `appsettings.json`, doesn't it work as expected?

Comment: This is exactly the right thing to do (it will even become mandatory with beta7, since the RSA key generation feature will be removed).

Comment: @ademcaglin I suppose this should work too. I choosed json approach for clear demonstration here.

Comment: Thanks @rudolfdobias . I just wanted to learn is there a special reason of using appsettings(i have wondered if it is a docker specific case).

Comment: @ademcaglin In this case - I'm loading configuration files along with keys from AWS S3 in CI build time. The certificate is stored in some binary format and I couldn't put in env variable anyway. And there are lots of settings in the json for defining it in envs. 
Better approach could be connecting to S3 directly from application startup via AWSSDK.S3 filesystem.